# Simple line of java code is catching a UnsupportedEncodingException and I can't figure out why

Tags: java, android, exception

I am completely stuck on this one. I know my code is correct. It is very simple. I have tried comparing what to `null`, using `.equals`, and now `.length()`, but it keeps catching this exception. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
public static void findLocations(String what, String near, String near2, String type) {
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url;
        String tempURL = "http://.........";

        if (what.length() != 0) { // This line is catching UnsupportedEncodingException
            tempURL += "&category=" + URLEncoder.encode(what, "UTF-8");
        }

        if (near.length() != 0) {


Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
LocationSet.findLocations(String, String, String, String) line: 85  
SearchAlgorithm.editNear() line: 322    
SearchAlgorithm.search(String, String) line: 90 
SearchView.onClick(View) line: 281  
Button(View).performClick() line: 2408  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816  
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Please add the full code. Also, it's not *catching* an exception, it's *throwing* one.

Comment: That line cannot possibly be *catching* any exception.  I assume you mean that it is *throwing* the exception.  And I don't think it could possibly be thrown by the line you indicate.  It is probably thrown by the URLEncoder.encode() call.  I suggest you post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Can you label which line is line 85? And is that the *full* output? I don't see "UnsupportedEncodingException" anywhere in the output.

Comment: *"I know my code is correct."*  If that's the case then it is obviously a bug in the run-time. <DWS>Raise a bug report.</DWS>

Comment: line 85 is)   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ue) {}

Comment: Then your code paste has gone funny, cause I don't see a catch in the code.  Maybe reformat it or something?  We're missing key lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

> public static String encode(String s,
>                               String enc)
>                        throws UnsupportedEncodingException

The methode "URLENCODER.encode(what, "UTF-8") is the line, where you get the exception.

Comment: it shouldnt be entering that if statement because what = ""

Comment: Are you sure it is "" and not " "? Did you try: what.trim().length() ? Use the debug mode and figure out why it enter the if-statment.

Comment: i am using the debugger. it is being very weird. it never enters the if statement. what.length() is returning 0 so it should not enter it. However it is throwing the UnsupportedEncodingException when it does that line of code, if (what.length() != 0)

Comment: im gonna exit it all and turn it back on and see wut happens

Comment: this is messed up restarting it didnt do anything. what do you mean a "clean"

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? If try "Project" -> "Clean..."

Comment: Did you try to catch the exception in the If-Statement? I mean not surround the if-statment with the try-catch...

Comment: oh no. i didnt think of that. thank you. that would work. ill do that now

Comment: Realy? Intresting. That must mean, that even if it not access the If-Statment, the exception would be thrown... Wired stuff!